# C# Android String to Double conversion ignores decimal point

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I'd like to convert a string to a double for some further calculations and while the following code snippet

```
double uValue = Convert.ToDouble(uText.Text);
```

works perfectly on the Android Emulator (Android 6.0, ARM processor), as soon as I try it on my phone (Xperia Z3 Compact, Android 6.0) via ADB, the converted value is somehow missing the decimal point.

As an example, if `uText.Text = "20.6"`, then the value of `uValue` is 206. How can I fix this?

Comment: have you checked the locale setting on the device?

Comment: is `Convert.ToDouble` culture-dependant ? maybe you can try with "20,6" to check that

Comment: @Jason The code works if I change my phone language from german to english...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed the code a little bit reagarding Jason's and AdricoM's comments, and now it works!

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");

double uValue = Convert.ToDouble(uText.Text, culture);
```

Thanks!